# Locus of constant length focal chords

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the continuous curve whose arithmetic mean (AM) of focal chord segments $OP,OQ$ is constant i.e., $O$ is focus through which focal ray straight line $PQ$ passes.

More briefly stated:

***Find the continuous curve intersected by straight focal segments of constant length PQ.***

So if found it may be called *CLCCC* ( const length central chord curve)

(Constant geometric mean GM locus is an *eccentric circle* and constant harmonic mean HM locus is a  *conic*, where HM = its *latus-rectum*).

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your question. Is O the focus? And are O, P, and Q collinear such that PQ is the focal chord? Also, I assume you are looking for a conic solution as focus isn't defined well for non conics. If all these are the case, then I believe you have yourself a circle again, and that is all.

Comment: Yes, that is why $GM ,HM $ loci indicated.

Comment: Great, now you do see why using a circle again will work? Are you looking for a proof that nothing else does?

Comment: A circle is a locus of constant GM of $OP,OQ$ not AM.

Comment: But $OP$=$OQ$ in a circle, that is why it works for AM AND GM (and HM for that matter).

Comment: Shall we go for a chat? The examples you gave are special trivial cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57771/discussion-between-isaac-browne-and-narasimham).

Comment: It is true that, if $O$ is a point inside a circle and $POQ$ is any chord through $O$, then $PO\cdot QO=k^2$ (constant). But you cannot say that circle to be the LOCUS of points $P$, $Q$ such that $PO\cdot QO=k^2$, because there are other points satisfying that relation, in addition to those of the circle.

Comment: This and its converse are in the Euclid's elements, is true up to Euclidean motions (rotations/translations). If there are any.. please state what those other points/loci are...or indicate leads and references.

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question.

[image: CLCCC]

The new $CLCCC$ has a line segment of constant length $w= PQ$ rotating around origin/focus while simultaneously sliding through it creating loops as shown.

At chord end of green sliding and rotating segment the arc rate of radius-relative angle $\psi$ is constant.

$$ \frac{d \psi}{ds}= \frac{1}{a},$$

where radius of curvature at points of tangency is $( r = w/2, \psi=0,  \kappa_g = 1/a). $

EDIT1

An end of a thin rigid rod inserted into a transverse hole of a circular bush can be slid arbitrarily but it is not be possible to make both the ends pass along a same continuous curve.